# Fedex Shipping Method Setup In Magento 1.9.0.1

Tags: magento, fedex

I am trying to setup FedEx shipping method in Magento (version 1.9.0.1).

I set shipping title as Federal Express and also filled the correct Account Id, Meter Number, Key, and Password given by the FedEx service.

I also Set Weight Unit in Pounds and Maximum Package Weight to 105.

I have also enabled the FedEx Shipping Method For Checkout. But I got the error message like Sorry, no quotes are available for this order at this time.

Answer (score 1):

I too was stuck with the same problem for several days.But finally i got it done.

The issue for me was the address.You need to verify two addresses:

1. The shipping origin address of the admin. You can set it in your admin panel.

> System->Configuration->Sales->shipping setting->Origin

Here enter the country and all information like zipcode,address etc.See this is correctly entered.

2. Another thing you need to keep in your mind is while checkout the address should be correct.

One thing you need to know while creating the fedex test account.

If you are shipping internationally from US and other countries than you need to select **US and Global** option while getting your meter number and account id.

If you want to test for domestic shipping out of US i.e for other countries than you need to select specific countries while getting your Fedex credential.

This should be done only for test credentials, For production environment single credentials will work for both domestic and international.

Currently the domestic shipping of UK is not working may be for other countries too so stop wasting your time on that if you are doing so.

The main thing in the address is the zip/postal code, you should enter a valid zip/code otherwise it will not work.

Try this and get in touch if some problems occur.May be i could help.

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: Thanks aton for answer.

Comment: Does that work for you? If yes than don't forget to accept the answer and vote.Happy Coding!!